# Prevent select2 from opening when a tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

This question evolved into preventing the dropdown from opening on enter key press. As you can see, my ugly solution closes the dropdown with a `setTimeout` when you press enter when a tag input has focus. How can I prevent it from opening at all on enter, instead of closing it after it has opened?

Here are some events that may be useful:
https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

```js
var tagClick = false;
$(document).on('mousedown touchstart', '.tag', function(e) {
  var $self = $(this);
  tagClick = true;
});
$(document).on('click', '.tag', function(e) {
  var $self = $(this);
  var $input = $self.find('input');
  $input.select();
});
$(document).on('blur', '.tag input', function(e) {
  var $self = $(this);
  $self.attr('value', $self.val());
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".tags").select2('close');
  }, 100);
  // Save to db here
});
$(document).on('keydown', '.tag input', function(e) {
 var nl = e.keyCode == 13; // is enter?
 var $self = $(this);
 if( nl )
 {
  $self.blur();
 }
});

$(".tags").select2({
    templateSelection: function(argSelection)
    {
      return $.parseHTML('<span class="tag">'+(argSelection.name || argSelection.text)+'<input type="text" value="" /></span>');
    },
  tags: true,
  width: '100%'
})
.on('select2:opening', function (e) {
  var $self = $(this);
  if( tagClick )
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    tagClick = false;
  }
})
```

```css
.tag input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.tag input[value=""]:not(:focus) {
  width: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="tags" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected="selected">purple</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

After reading some documentation about the [event listeners](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events#listening-for-events), I wrote this code that works only when you click on the cross to remove a tag, please specify if you wish to prevent the dropdown if the whole tag gets clicked and I will look on it, here is the code, basically, we're hearing for `select2:unselecting` event and preventing the drop-down menu to show by preventing its proper opening event to trigger :

```
$(".tags").on('select2:unselecting', function (e) { 
  $(".tags").on('select2:opening', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(".tags").off('select2:opening');
  });
});
```

Working snippet below :

```js
$(".tags").select2({
  tags: true,
  width: '100%'
});

$(".tags").on('select2:unselecting', function (e) { 
  $(".tags").on('select2:opening', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(".tags").off('select2:opening');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="tags" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected="selected">purple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! I want the dropdown list to NOT open at all if you click on the tag, not even the text. The reason for this is that I want to add a click event to the tag text that opens additional options for that tag alone, and there is no need to open the dropdown menu for that.

Comment: I updated my code above. If you can find a cleaner version that I can run inside select2 instead of on mousedown that would be cool. This seems a little hacky and also doesn't work on older browsers it seems.

Comment: Sorry for updating this topic, but I think I'm making headway. Now I need to figure out how to prevent the dropdown from opening when the input is blurred with the enter key. It kinda works, but not 100% of the time. Ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah its kinda tricky, even when I tried to preventDefault() on click on the tag span it doesn't work...

Comment: Yes, because click comes after the select2 event. on mousdown is before though so I could use that.

Answer (score 0):

According to this github [comment](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3209#issuecomment-457076036), official workaround for this issue is a bit simpler as:

```
$("select").on('select2:unselecting', event => {
    if (!event.params.args.originalEvent) return;
    event.params.args.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$(".tags").select2({
  tags: true,
  width: '100%'
}).on('select2:unselecting', event => {
  if (!event.params.args.originalEvent) return;
  event.params.args.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="tags" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option selected="selected">purple</option>
</select>
```

Please note that this workaround works only for multiselect, NOT for single select